# Ffmpeg mixing audio only for n number of videos using offset with an altered duration

Tags: audio, ffmpeg

I want to mix audio stream of n amount of video files with ffmpeg, with certain parameters such as:

- Duration: I want to specify how long each audio is going to play for each output. For example if I specify `ffmpeg -i -d:5 first.mp4 -i second.mp4` it should play the audio from `first.mp4` for 5 seconds (I don't know if `-d:5` is a real tag it's just an example I've made ).
- Starting point: I want to specify when a given file is going start on the output, I probably need to use `-itsoffset 5` but I don't know if it's the right one in terms of interacting with other commands, in on itself it works fine. For example: `ffmpeg -i -isoffset 5 first.mp -i second.mp4` causes the `second.mp4` to start immediately, and first.mp4 to start after 5 seconds.
- Segmentation: This is the tricky one, I want to specify at which point the input's audio should start. It's like the `-ss` flag but the problem is it's not working together with `-itsoffset`. For example when I say `ffmpeg -i -ss 5 first.mp4 -i second.mp4` both files should start immediately on the output, but `first.mp4` should start on it's 5 seconds. So the 5th second of `first.mp4` is heard at the 1st second of the output.

This is what I'm trying to achieve, **my problem is** that I don't know how to implement 'duration' and `-ss` is not working together with `-itsoffset`.

At the end I should have something similar to this:

```
ffmpeg -y -d 5 -itsoffset 3.5 -i first.mp4 -d 10 -ss 10 -itsoffset 5.3 -i 3 -vn -copyts -async 1 -filter_complex amix=inputs=2 out.mp
```

Which should result in an audio that sounds like this: The first 3.5 seconds are empty, no audio is heard. Then `first.mp4` is heard from it's beginning for 5 seconds. When the outputs timestamp reaches 5.3, the 10th seconds of `second.mp4` is heard (while `first.mp4` is still playing, it's supposed to play until 8.5, so I should hear both files at the same time.) for 10 seconds.

I can't find an example of this and some sources are out-of date.

Comment: I'd use `-ss` and `-t` input options to specify where to start extracting the audio on each input file. Then, use an `adelay` filter on each stream to position them on the output timeline before mixing them together with `mix` filter. IMO, this way is a lot cleaner than trying to manipulate and propagate input time stamps.

Comment: I tried this: `ffmpeg -y -ss 3 -t 4 -i first.mp4     -ss 5 -i second.mp4      -c:v copy -vn -filter_complex amix=inputs=2 out.mp4` but both videos start from the begining, not from the 4th second. `-ss` works fine but just like with `-itsoffset` , `-t` is not working together with `-ss` .

Comment: Should've phrased it to read "I'd ONLY use -ss and -t input options... "

Comment: @kesh Can you give an example similar to mine please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
ffmpeg -t  5 -ss  0 -i first.mp4 \
       -t 10 -ss 10 -i second.mp4 \
       -filter_complex \
         [0:a]adelay=3500:all=1[c1];\
         [1:a]adelay=5300:all=1[c2];\
         [c1][c2]amix=inputs=2[aout] \
       -map [aout] out.mp3
```